# Como alterar valores do input HTML com EditText utilizando WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview

Existe algum jeito de alterar um campo do formulário pegando o valor do EditText, usando um cliente WebView ?
Tenho uma aplicação no qual acessa meu site e lá tem 2 campos, um de usuário e outro de senha, quando digito nos "EditText" o usuário e a senha, preciso que esse valor passe para o formulário html.

Segue o código da classe responsável pela abertura do site:

```
public class Site extends Tela1 {

    static WebView site;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_website);

        site = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);


        WebSettings settings = site.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.supportZoom();
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        settings.setTextZoom(150);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);


        site.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        site.loadUrl("javascript:var elem = document.getElementById('user').value = 'My default value';");

        MyWebViewClient cliente = new MyWebViewClient();

        cliente.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(site, dadosDominio.trim());


    }
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;

        }

    }





}
```

CÓDIGO HTML:

```
<form novalidate id="login_form" action="/login/" method="post" target="_top">
    <div class="input-req-login"><label for="user">Nome de usuário</label></div>
    <div class="input-field-login icon username-container">
        <input name="user" id="user" autofocus="autofocus" value="" placeholder="Digite seu nome de usuário." class="std_textbox" type="text"  tabindex="1" required>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:30px;" class="input-req-login"><label for="pass">Senha</label></div>
    <div class="input-field-login icon password-container">
        <input name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Digite a senha da conta." class="std_textbox" type="password" tabindex="2"  required>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="login-btn">
            <button name="login" type="submit" id="login_submit" tabindex="3">Login</button>
        </div>

                                    </div>
    <div class="clear" id="push"></div>
</form>
```

LOG:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/BrowserProcessMain: Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
W/chromium: [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null", source:  (1)
I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
```

Comment: O id `user` existe ?

Comment: Sim, existe. Coloquei agora o código HTML acima para vocês verem se estou fazendo algo errado..